# Why is the next function not working in R studio for me here

Tags: r, while-loop

I need to iterate from 2 to 6 and skip the number 4.

This is what I got so far

```
#/!/usr/bin/env/R

i <-2
 while(i < 7)
{
  if( i == 4)
  {
    next 
  }
  print(i)
  i = i + 1
 }
```

when I run this in [r](/questions/tagged/r), it just stops at 3
and when ever I try to add the next command, it automatically adds bracket changing it to `next()`.

It also messes up the console as nothing works until in the console until I stop the console and refresh it, the code works perfectly fine if I replace next with break but doesn't work this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still need to iterate i in the if statement, otherwise it will loop forever.

```
i <-2
 while(i < 7)
{
  if( i == 4)
  {
    i=i+1
    next  
  }
  print(i)
  i = i + 1
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would flip the logic and move the print inside the if:

```
i <-2
while(i < 7){
  if( i != 4)
  {
    print(i)
  }
  i <- i + 1
}
```